# Arduino overflow

Tags: types, arduino, overflow

So I am following [this tutorial](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/lesson4.html) to get familiar with Arduino. At the end of the lesson the author tries to test my understanding of basic math operations, concept of bits and bytes, and how to use appropriate type of data by asking me to write a program that is capable of converting any given GB to KB. I thought it was an easy task. But I thought wrong.

So here is my original code:

```
long drive_gb = 100; //given number
long drive_kb;
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);

   Serial.print("Your HD is ");
   Serial.print(drive_gb);
   Serial.println(" GB large.");


   drive_kb = 1024*1024*drive_gb;

   Serial.print("It can store ");
   Serial.print(drive_kb);
   Serial.println(" Kilobytes!");

 }

 void loop()
 {
 }
```

but when I check out my serial monitor I get this output:

"Your HD is 100 GB large.
It can store 0 Kilobytes!"

I then modified my code to this:

```
long drive_gb = 100;
 long drive_kb;
 long drive_mb;
 void setup()

 {
   Serial.begin(9600);

   Serial.print("Your HD is ");
   Serial.print(drive_gb);
   Serial.println(" GB large.");

   drive_mb = 1024*drive_gb;
   drive_kb = 1024*drive_mb;

   Serial.print("It can store ");
   Serial.print(drive_kb);
   Serial.println(" Kilobytes!");

 }

 void loop()
 {
 }
```

And now I get correct output

"Your HD is 100 GB large.
It can store 104857600 Kilobytes!
"

So my questions are:

1. Is the first code resulting an overflow situation? How?
2. How is the first code mathematically different from the second code?

Thanks!

Comment: 100 GB = 100000000 kB. SI prefixes are always used in the original decimal meaning by the HD industry.

Answer (score 2):

To get a definitive answer you would to list the assembly code that the compiler generated in the first example.

My guess is that the code for `X = 1024 * 1024 * Y;` did not account for the fact that a long is required to store the result and the generated code used ints instead.

Try: `X = 1024L * 1024L * Y;` and see if you get the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've been trying to get the assembly code by using avr-objdump -S in command prompt but I don't think it recognizes that command. Is there a better way to view the assembly code?

Answer (score 1):

- `1024*1024*drive_gb` means `(1024*1024)*drive_gb` because, per the C standard, multiplication is left-to-right associative.
- `1024` means `(int) 1024` because decimal constants have the first type that can fit them among (int, long, unsigned long).
- `1024*1024` being the product of two ints, the result will also be an int.
- on the Arduino platform (actually AVR), ints are 16 bits, thus the above product overflows.

You could get the correct result just by writing

```
drive_kb = 1024*(1024*drive_gb);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play with overflows, it's advisable to either leverage constatns suchs as MAX_INT (if available) or rely on more system-specific types, like uint32_t, which stat eexplicitly how many bytes/bit as available.